# group twice in one query

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, group-by

I use below code but doesn't return what I expect,

the table relationship,
each `gallery` is include multiple `media` and each media is include multiple `media_user_action`. 
I want to count each `gallery` how many `media_user_action` and order by this count

```
rows: [
 {
   "id": 1
 },
 {
   "id": 2
 }
]
```

and this query will return duplicate gallery rows something like

```
rows: [
 {
   "id": 1
 },
 {
   "id": 1
 },
 {
   "id": 2
 }
 ...
]
```

I think because in the `LEFT JOIN` subquery select `media_user_action` rows only group by `media_id`, 
need to group by `gallery_id` also ?

```
SELECT
 g.*
 FROM gallery g 
   LEFT JOIN gallery_media gm ON gm.gallery_id = g.id
   LEFT JOIN (
     SELECT 
       media_id, 
       COUNT(*) as mua_count
       FROM media_user_action
       WHERE type = 0
       GROUP BY media_id
   ) mua ON mua.media_id = gm.media_id
   ORDER BY g.id desc NULLS LAST OFFSET $1 LIMIT $2
```

table

```
gallery
id |
1  |
2  |

gallery_media
id | gallery_id fk gallery.id | media_id fk media.id
1  | 1                        | 1
2  | 1                        | 2
3  | 2                        | 3
....

media_user_action
id | media_id fk media.id | user_id | type
1  | 1                    | 1       | 0
2  | 1                    | 2       | 0
3  | 3                    | 1       | 0
...

media
id | 
1  |
2  |
3  |
```

**UPDATE**
There's more other table I need to select, this is a part in a function like this https://jsfiddle.net/g8wtqqqa/1/  when user input option then build query.

So I correct my question I need to find a way if user want to count `media_user_action` order by it, I wanna know how to put these in a subquery possible not change any other code

Base on below @trincot answer I update code, only add `media_count` on top change a little bit and put those in sub query. is what I want,
now they are group by gallery.id, but sort media_count desc and asc are same result not working I can't find why?

```
SELECT
 g.*,
 row_to_json(gi.*) as gallery_information,
 row_to_json(gl.*) as gallery_limit,
 media_count
 FROM gallery g 
 LEFT JOIN gallery_information gi ON gi.gallery_id = g.id
 LEFT JOIN gallery_limit gl ON gl.gallery_id = g.id
 LEFT JOIN "user" u ON u.id = g.create_by_user_id
 LEFT JOIN category_gallery cg ON cg.gallery_id = g.id
 LEFT JOIN category c ON c.id = cg.category_id 
   LEFT JOIN (
     SELECT 
       gm.gallery_id,
       COUNT(DISTINCT mua.media_id) media_count
       FROM gallery_media gm
       INNER JOIN media_user_action mua
         ON mua.media_id = gm.media_id AND mua.type = 0
       GROUP BY gm.gallery_id
   ) gm ON gm.gallery_id = g.id
   ORDER BY gm.media_count asc NULLS LAST OFFSET $1 LIMIT $2
```

Comment: I've posted an answer explaining why you get duplicates, thus answering your question. You may want to make a separate request telling what you actually want to achieve and how your query result is different from what you want. (If you only wanted all gallery records, you could `select * from gallery`, so this is probably not what you are after.)

Comment: thanks for reply, I update in question all my query I want to select gallery and other relation table

Comment: The added "edit" to your question is a different question. It involves other tables, and another problem.

Comment: the added table is the reason I want to use join in my original question,  I want to make data output like that, so maybe ignore those added table.. and I want to find how to extend in left join count media_user_action table

Comment: What about those row_to_json strings in your select list. Do you use them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The join with *gallery_media* table is multiplying your results. The count and grouping should happen after you have made that join.

You could achieve that like this:

```
SELECT    g.id,
          COUNT(DISTINCT mua.media_id)
FROM      gallery g
LEFT JOIN gallery_media gm
       ON gm.gallery_id = g.id
LEFT JOIN media_user_action mua
       ON mua.media_id = gm.id AND type = 0
GROUP BY  g.id
ORDER BY  2 DESC
```

If you need the other informations as well, you could use the above (in simplified form) as a sub-query, which you join with anything else that you need, but will not multiply the number of rows:

```
SELECT    g.*
          row_to_json(gi.*) as gallery_information,
          row_to_json(gl.*) as gallery_limit,
          media_count
FROM      gallery g
LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT     gm.gallery_id,
                       COUNT(DISTINCT mua.media_id) media_count
            FROM       gallery_media gm
            INNER JOIN media_user_action mua
                    ON mua.media_id = gm.id AND type = 0
            GROUP BY   gm.gallery_id
          ) gm
       ON gm.gallery_id = g.id
LEFT JOIN gallery_information gi ON gi.gallery_id = g.id
LEFT JOIN gallery_limit gl ON gl.gallery_id = g.id
ORDER BY  media_count DESC NULLS LAST 
OFFSET    $1
LIMIT     $2
```

The above assumes that *gallery_id* is unique in the tables *gallery_information* and *gallery_limit*.

Comment: the sort desc and asc are some result  https://jsfiddle.net/grvbf9jv/1/ do i miss something

Comment: You mean **same** result? I don't understand what you are saying... Could you make an [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) instead of a JS fiddle?

Comment: oh they are group by gallery_id now, but output desc and asc are same like desc > id:1 id:2 asc > id:1 id:2,

Comment: But what is the value of media_count for each of them?

Comment: they are different gallery 1 has multiple rows in  media_user_action , and gallery 2 no rows

Comment: Could you create a SQL fiddle with your tables and data. Also make sure when you manually count media_user_action rows, you take the filter type=0 into account which is in the query. I asked for the value of media_count for each of them. What does the query return for media_count?

Comment: sql fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/57dbf/2 seems work ?? I check my original code now

Comment: I think I found out why same result http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d3ae5/2 if gallery 3 don't have media media_count null

Comment: Thanks so much for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

You're grouping by `media_id` to get a count, but since one `gallery` can have many `gallery_media`, you still end up with multiple rows for one `gallery`. You can either sum the `mua_count` from your subselect:

```
SELECT g.*, sum(mua_count)
FROM gallery g 
LEFT JOIN gallery_media gm ON gm.gallery_id = g.id
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT media_id, 
  COUNT(*) as mua_count
  FROM media_user_action
  WHERE type = 0
  GROUP BY media_id
) mua ON mua.media_id = gm.media_id
GROUP BY g.id
ORDER BY g.id desc NULLS LAST;
```

```
 id | sum
----+-----
  2 |   1
  1 |   2
```

Or you can just `JOIN` all the way through and group once on `g.id`:

```
SELECT g.id, count(*)
FROM gallery g
JOIN gallery_media gm ON gm.gallery_id = g.id
JOIN media_user_action mua ON mua.media_id = gm.id
GROUP BY g.id
ORDER BY count DESC;
```

```
 id | count
----+-------
  1 |     2
  2 |     1
```

Comment: thanks for reply I following your code and I got error, I post in question

Comment: Everything that's not an aggregate function (`count`, `sum`, etc.) must appear in the `GROUP BY` clause. For your new query, that would mean `GROUP BY g.*, gi.*, gl.*`, but that's getting sort of out of hand. Try fetching just `g.id, count` in a subquery, then join to `gi` and `gl` to get the rest of the data.

Comment: is there any way I can put all relate count media_user_action in one subquery not change others?

Comment: There are lots of ways to do lots of things, but I'm not sure what you mean. It might be time to [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), and link back to this one to provide context.

Comment: this is I made for https://jsfiddle.net/g8wtqqqa/ , the query is in a javascript function when use put different option output different query, I tried to find how to put the code in question select media_user_action in sub query , so if I remove that, won't change other lines

Answer (score -1):

If you only want to show data from table `gallery` (with `select g.*`) then why do you join the other tables? Outer joins either join one ore more records to each main record (depending on how many matches are found in the outer-joined table), so no surprise you get duplicates (in your case because gallery ID 1 has two matches in `gallery_media`).

Comment: I don't understand why this was downvoted. By outer joining tables to a main table you get the number of records in main or more. And the sample data show why it is more in this case. So I think my answer is complete. (As to the query: I mentioned in the comments section that the query could have been simplified to `select * from gallery` in order to avoid duplicates. The second query was only shown after I had posted my answer.)